# How do I convert my PHP api call into JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to make API calls every time a click event happens. I thought I would try to use JavaScript to make a call even though I have PHP for it; in order to make it reliable.

This is my php code for the API call that I'm making:

```
      // create curl resource
      $ch = curl_init();
      // set url 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?" . 
      "language=en");


      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));

      // $output contains the output json
      $output = curl_exec($ch);
      // close curl resource to free up system resources 
      curl_close($ch);


      $outputArray = json_decode($output, true);


      echo "<br><br><br><br>" . $outputArray['text'];
```

This is my JavaScript code for the click function:

```
      $(function() {

         $('#b1').click(

            function() {

                $('#input').val(val);

      } ); });
```

My goal is to translate the same API call I made in PHP into JavaScript. And place it into the function. However, it took me a while to figure out how to set up the API call in the first place. This is why I'm not sure if my API call can be made the same way.

Comment: So, your frontend JS should call a backend PHP script, that's the problem or you want a direct API call from JS?  If first, just wrap it up inside of some XHR request and parse the response once received. I see you're using jQuery so you can use `$.get()` or `$.post()`, to simplify stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to place the call into JS because I need to make a new API call every time I make a click. So I don't want to call the backend script. But XHR request sounds like the JS way, and the function and parameters set-up is probably different. Which is my issue

Comment: @icwebndev I don't think that will work if it is a different domain though, unless the service supports JSONP. Otherwise the request for the JSON data will be blocked. A workaround would be to use something like Ajax Cross Origin plugin for jQuery. http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/

Comment: @icwebndev CORS is for overriding the context-based security, the request will only work if CORS is implemented (or if the request is made to the same domain as the page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer bolow code of JS

```
$(document).on('click','#b1',function(){ 
       var response = $.get('https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?language=en') 
       if(response && response.text){
          console.log(response.text);
          $('#input').val(response.text);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The get attempt I made with PHP required some specific parameters so I tried this code and it did not make a successful response. It's a good answer though.

Comment: My domain works pretty normal I have worked with it a lot.I believe I need to pass the headers.

Comment: @Newton If the above URL is accurate then no that is not the issue. I can access the response with Chrome which used this in the accept header `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3`... I don't think it really matters what is in that header.